# Why Wi-Fi is getting turned-on automatically in iOS 11

Tags: wifi, ios

I am using iOS 11 in iPhone 5S but its wi-fi is getting turned-on automatically, is there any way to stop it.

Answer (score 4):

[Source](https://www.imobie.com/support/fix-ios-11-wifi-turns-on-by-itself.htm):

Beginning in iOS 11, the system will automatically try and reconnect to known devices using Bluetooth and Wi-Fi at 5am every morning (local time) if they have only been toggled off using the **Control Center**.

You 'fix' this behaviour by turning both radios off inside of `Settings' (depending on your device locale and language, "Wi-Fi" might also be named "WLAN" as in the pictures below):

1. Open `Settings -> Wi-Fi`.
2. Switch the `Wi-Fi` radio button to off.

[image]